# Disbale autofill to form elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, google-chrome, autocomplete

I want to disable autofill password popup to my form elements.

This is my current form but the issue is that id does not even a password fill but unfortunately still appear password suggestion in chrome Version 84.

I've tried those solution but it does not work is bellow.

```
1) Used autocomplete='nope'
2) Used autocomplete='new-password'
3) Used autocomplete='off'
4) Used autocomplete='false'
5) Used Autocomplete Jquery
```

But, non of sultion is worked for me.

Code.

```
<form id="saveSettingsForm" class="form-horizontal" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="number" step="1" class="form-control fourth-btn-dotation cannon_speed_1 speed_update" style="margin:auto;" autocomplete="nope">
</form>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disabling Chrome Autofill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738259/disabling-chrome-autofill)